# Share code in F# Azure Functions project

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

I'm currently developing F# Azure functions uinsg VS Code and I've laid out my project as such:

```
ProjectFolder
    -> Function1
        -> function.json
        -> run.fsx
    -> Function2
        -> function.json
        -> run.fsx
```

Given that F# doesn't support folders what's the best way to share code (especially types) between the two functions?

Comment: I recommend using an fsproj (pre-compiled) for Azure Functions instead of scripts. Especially if you want to share code between functions. There are only advantages to pre-compiled. You won't be able to use a VS Azure Functions project but you don't need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# compiler supports folders just fine. You may be referring to the fact that Visual Studio, in default configuration, does not allow one to add folders to F# projects - that is a true fact. But if you do somehow manage to add folders to your project file (either by manually editing the file, or with [F# Power Tools](https://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/)), then the F# compiler won't have any problems with them.

But this is all irrelevant to your case anyway, because scripts (`fsx`) are not the same thing as compiled modules (`fs`). Scripts do not have a project to bind them together, and instead must `#load` each other in order to use each other's code. And `#load` can be done from any path whatsoever.

For example, you might want to lay out your code like this:

```
ProjectFolder
    -> Common
        -> Helpers.fsx
    -> Function1
        -> function.json
        -> run.fsx
    -> Function2
        -> function.json
        -> run.fsx
```

And then, within `Function1/run.fsx`, load the file `Helpers.fsx` using relative path:

```
// Function1/run.fsx
#load "../Common/Helpers.fsx"

let x = Helpers.someFunction()
```

As is evident from the example above, a script loaded this way will appear within the host script as a module named after the script file.

This works, but over time it will become very messy. I highly recommend going with precompiled code instead. This way, you can put common code in a shared library and reference it from both functions.

I very much recommend [this recent video from NDC Oslo](https://vimeo.com/223985427). It talks very well about these things and more.

Comment: Should I even bother including non script files with namespaces/modules etc.. ?

Comment: Yes, you can include non-script files, too. They'll just be a bit awkward to use, but they'll work. But I do not recommend it. Like I said, I recommend precompiling.

Comment: I had that video in my instapaper queue :)